# Simultaneously predict fields with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I wanted to simultaneously predict the total volume and volume of class A, B, C, D, and 0.
Is it possible to do this with the code below? Do I have to add a field in the dataset with what I'm predicting?

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataAnalysis/data/featureEngineering/data.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:20].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 21:26].values
# 21 - 'VOLUME_CLASSE_A'
# 22 - 'VOLUME_CLASSE_B'
# 23 - 'VOLUME_CLASSE_C'
# 24 - 'VOLUME_CLASSE_D'
# 25 - 'VOLUME_CLASSE_0'
# 26 - 'TOTAL_VOLUME'

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
test_predictions = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: What do you mean "*is it possible*"? You have run the code, what do you get as output? Are you getting errors or something?

Comment: The code works and runs without errors, but I don't think it's doing what I want.

Comment: Why *exactly* do you think so? Don't you get a multi-output from your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to do that with the code below since RandomForestRegressor supports multioutput. In case you want to try different models that don't support multioutput you should use either `MultiOutputRegressor` or `RegressorChain` from [sklearn multioutput](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput).

In a nutshell `MultiOutputRegressor` fits a model for each output variable and `RegressorChain` fits a model for each output variable but it also uses the previous models outputs as inputs this is why it's called **Chain**. Here is quick demonstration on how to use both strategies with:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor, RegressorChain
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True)

# MultiOutputRegressor
multi= MultiOutputRegressor(Ridge(random_state=123))
multi.fit(X, y)

# RegressorChain
# Starting with the second output variable, then first then third
re = RegressorChain(base_estimator=Ridge(random_state=123), order=[1,0,2])
re.fit(X,y)
```

You can find a list of the models that support multioutput and more info [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)